# How do I access a text field from ajaxcontroltoolkit htmleditor control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function (I inherited the code and am new to .Net) that is defined as

```
private void setTextBoxes(DataView dv, FCKeditor txtField, HiddenField hidField)
```

We were using the ckEditorv2 (FckEditorv2), but due to incompatibility issues they want to go to just use the ajaxcontroltoolkit htmleditor. I cannot figure out what to put in place of FCKEditor in the above code call. I have tried various things like HTMLEditor, ajaxeditor and cannot figure what this is really pulling and how I access it or replace it with the ajax control instead of the FCKEditor control.

Thank you for any help you can give me.

wb

ANSWER:
It turns out I was not using the correct collection. I was using AjaxControlToolKit and I needed to (perhaps also) use AjaxControlToolKit.HTMLEditor. Once I used that collection it recognized Editor as the correct parameter type and then I just had to clean up the code (such as AjaxControlToolKit does not have .value, it is .content) and it works!

Comment: I figured it out. I was using ajaxcontroltoolkit but not ajaxcontroltoolkit.htmleditor, which meant it did not about the editor. So, I included the correct collection, used the proper parameter type and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: It turns out I was not using the correct collection. I was using AjaxControlToolKit and I needed to (perhaps also) use AjaxControlToolKit.HTMLEditor. Once I used that collection it recognized Editor as the correct parameter type and then I just had to clean up the code (such as AjaxControlToolKit does not have .value, it is .content) and it works!